# Best way to inicialize multiple attributes in python classes

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a simple class with 50+ attributes. All of them will be set up as empty string when the class is created. What is the best pythonic way of doing it?

Should it be like that?

```
att1 = att2 = att3 ... = att100 = ''
```

Or:

```
att1 = ''
att2 = ''
...
att100 = ''
```

Comment: `for x in range(1, 101): setattr(self, f"att{x}", "")`, maybe? But a class with 50-100 attributes seems a bit much and [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761) are generally a bad idea - can you give some context as to why you need this?

Comment: @ jonrsharpe I am making a parser of a custom text file. But actually now that you commented, it migth be better to create one field with a dictionary to map this values, rigth?

Comment: Definitely using a dictionary or a list is the way to go